# Fourier series and Integrals

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Let $F_N$ be Fejer kernal,namely $F_N=\dfrac{1}{N+1}(\dfrac{sin(\pi(N+1)t))}{sin(\pi t)})^2$.If $f\in L^p$,has period $1$,$\sigma_N f(x)=\int_0^1f(x-t)F_N(t)dt$,
my question is why the following equation is ture?
$$\lVert \sigma_Nf-f\rVert_p=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\lVert f(x-t)-f(x)\rVert_pF_N(t)dt$$ 
By my calculation,I believe that
$$\lVert \sigma_Nf-f\rVert_p=\lVert\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}(f(x-t)-f(x))F_N(t)dt\rVert_p$$

Comment: By Minkowski's inequality,I can got an inequality.

Comment: Equality is not true. You can only say $\leq $.